# Arithmetic Operations inside XAML Resource Dictionary

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary, ivalueconverter

#### What I want to do

I've been exploring XAML Resource Dictionaries recently. They are very powerful, but in order to cut down (even further) on the changes that would need to be made to accommodate any modifications, I'd like to use some basic arithmetic operations to change the `HeightRequest` property of an `Entry`.

I'm already making good use of `OnPlatform` and `OnIdiom` for different aspects, like `FontSize`.

For the iOS Platform, I'd like to make the `HeightRequest` of an entry `20+(FontSize)`. The `FontSize` is already set using `OnIdiom` (it's slightly increased for tablets).

In a perfect world, the core thing which I'm trying to do might look something like 
`<Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}+10">`

#### What "works"

I have a *working* solution if I use a combination of `OnIdiom` and `OnPlatform`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinDesigner.App"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDesigner"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnIdiom x:Key="StandardFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double"  Tablet="22" Phone="18"/>
            <Style x:Key="MyEntry" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30"/>
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40"/>
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        </OnIdiom>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

With this 'solution' - I need to set the value explicitly and do the calculations myself. While this works, I'd like to be able to perform a basic arithmetic operation to find the value of `FontSize`, and add some number to it.

#### What I've tried

In another attempt I've made, [I've found a converter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2006/11/13/arithmetic-operations-in-xaml/) and tried to adapt it to my use case. While there is no intellisense or build/compile errors, the app crashes immediately after opening. The .cs file for ArithmeticConverter can be found in the link above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinDesigner.App"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDesigner"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:ArithmeticConverter x:Key="AScript"/>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnIdiom x:Key="StandardFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double"  Tablet="22" Phone="18"/>

            <Style x:Key="MyEntry" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AScript},ConverterParameter=Int32.Parse(20+{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}}"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I don't fully understand the use of converters, and `{Binding}` inside of a value in App.xaml is also something that is new to me. Looking at the example provided with the converter, I think I'm *close* to being correct, and may just need a push in the right direction?

---

Is it possible to do this basic sort of arithmetic function in the `App.xaml` alone(or with the use of a converter)? I'm hoping to contain as much as I can to this file.

Other solutions I've found in my search have mentioned the use of a viewmodel, but this is a 'global' change I want to apply to *every* entry per platform/idiom, so I can't see how that adaption might work.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you place a break point inside your converter, you'll see why it is crashing... For one thing, as opposed to the example you linked, you're not binding to anything, so your `value` within your converter will be null. Also, the regular expression used in the example most likely won't fit your needs. And yes, you can have all that inside App.xaml with no problem.

Comment: Here's a much cleaner solution: bind directly to your `StandardFontSize` and then do whatever math you need inside the converter itself. This way you eliminate the need for both, `ConverterParameter` and regular expressions.

Comment: Hmm, this is one way I could go about this, but it gets a little tricky around my usecase/intentions I think. I'm effectively trying to set up the equivalent of a CSS, and trying to steer clear of Binding where I can, as I'm going over an existing application updating the styling (which does not currently utilise resource dictionaries). Many of the pages already have quite complex binding setups to other classes and models. 

Regardless, I'll play with that concept and see what I can come up with! Thanks for your response.

Comment: I very much look forward to see what you'll come up with. Please post your solution once you have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reason your app is crashing is because Converter is outside the ResourceDictionary.

**Solution 1**

Binding should be used only when there is a BindingContext assigned, hence you need to assign it in cs file.

App.cs:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new { EntryHeightRequest = 10 };
    MainPage = ...
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:ArithmeticConverter x:Key="AScript"/>
    <OnIdiom x:Key="StandardFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double"  Tablet="22" Phone="18"/>
    <Style x:Key="MyEntry" TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}" /> 
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{Binding EntryHeightRequest, Converter={StaticResource AScript},ConverterParameter="{StaticResource StandardFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

ArithmeticConverter.cs:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if(value is int constant && parameter is OnIdiom<double> dynamicSize)
        return constant + dynamicSize.GetValue();
    return -1;
}
```

OnIdiomExtension:

```
    public static T GetValue<T>(this OnIdiom<T> idiom)
    {
        switch(Device.Idiom)
        {
            case TargetIdiom.Phone:
                return idiom.Phone;

            case TargetIdiom.Desktop:
                return idiom.Desktop;

            case TargetIdiom.Tablet:
                return idiom.Tablet;

            case TargetIdiom.TV:
                return idiom.TV;

            case TargetIdiom.Watch:
                return idiom.Watch;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

**Beware**: When I tried, BindingContext is passed to  ResourceDictionary([but this post contradicts it, may be they changed?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/51280/xaml-binding-within-a-resource-dictionary-contentpage-resources-does-not-work))

**Solution 2**

Similar to **Solution 1** but instead of setting BindingContext you can use OnIdiom on HeightRequest with default value.

```
<Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{OnIdiom Default=10, Converter={StaticResource AScript}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource StandardFontSize}}" />
```

Comment: Even if the converter is placed inside resource dictionary, it will still crash because there are other more "serious" problems, like i mentioned in my comment.